# What is the role of parameters in whale optimization algorithm?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I am trying to understand how the whale optimization algorithm works. When I see the mathematical model of this algorithm there are some parameters I want to understand what they mean and what their roles are. As in the figure the exploration shows some equation. What is the role of the parameter $C$ when we calculate the distance?

> The search agent (humpback whale) looks for the best solution (the prey) randomly based on the position of each agent. We update the position of a search agent during this phase by using a randomly selected search agent rather than the best search agent. Following that, if $|a|>1$, as defined in Equation 3. then force the search agen to move away from a reference whale. Here's the mathematical model beind this phase: \begin{align}\vec D&=|\vec C\cdot\vec{X_{\rm rand}}-\vec X|\tag1\\\vec X(t+1)&=\vec{X_{\rm rand}}-\vec A\cdot\vec D\tag2\end{align} where $\vec{X_{\rm rand}}$ is a random position vector selected from the current population, and $\{\vec A,\vec C\}$ are coefficient vectors. Besides, here are the equations of $\{\vec A,\vec C\}$ that can be used to find the best search agents: \begin{align}\vec A&=2\cdot\vec a\cdot\vec r-\vec a\tag3\\\vec C&=2\cdot\vec r\tag4\end{align} where $\vec r$ is a random vector in range $[0,1]$ and $\vec a$ decreases linearly from $2$ to $0$ during the iterations.